# HTTP authenticating --- some weird way

Tags: javascript, request, request-promise

When I try to login emodal.com (I assume it uses basic authentication because it just requires a user/pass) on the browser it works fine and lets me go to a certain page and lets me through. However when I try to go in the page that I want and authenticate programmatically (using request or request-promise) it gets denied  because of "invalid credentials". It seems like I need to login manually through a browser or something by clicking the login button and THEN i would be able to go to the private protected page that I want (why doesn't it work programmatically whereas the browser (google chrome) works? Is it going through a second step in the authentication process that I am not aware of?)

Here I provided 3 screenshots of how the devtools console looks when I log in (it makes a request to ValidateWharfageUser, then Login, then GetStatus as shown, then I guess thats where it denies me programmatically).

```
import dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: '../logins.env' });
import rp = require('request-promise');
const jsonUrl = `http://availability.emodal.com/ImportAvailability/GetContainerInfoList?sgrdModel=%7B%22searchtext%22:%22%22,%22page%22:1,%22pageSize%22:280,%22sortBy%22:%221%22,%22sortDirection%22:%22asc%22,%22sortColumns%22:%22%22%7D`;

const authOpts = {
  uri: jsonUrl,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMODAL_id,
    pass: process.env.EMODAL_pw,
    sendImmediately: false
  },
  method: 'get'
}

rp(authOpts)
.then(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
}).catch(err => { throw Error(err)});
```

**The 3 screenshots:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW4Ka.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rakQl.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH1Hx.png

Comment: Sounds like you're sending invalid credentials. Or if what you are saying is you are trying to get to an auth protected page by sending credentials with your request, that would only work if their auth is set to check for credentials when handling the request. If they are using something like JWT, then you would first need to authenticate to get the JWT and pass the JWT with the request in the header under the correct key.

Comment: On my browser I went to the page that I wanted to go in by programmatically, and grabbed the JWT from the console. It expires Jun 16. Am I able to just send normal http requests by setting this in the header from now on  without doing this  jwt thing until june 16? Or does it not work like that

Comment: Yeah, so JWT is a JSON Web Token (encrypted string containing you auth information). The person setting up the authentication on the system you are accessing can set the time to live when generating the JWT. You can then set the JWT in your header and it will work until it expires. You will need to know what the header key is they are expecting to find the JWT under though. https://jwt.io/introduction/